# Accessing the elements of an array inside an object in D3

Tags: javascript, json, object, d3.js

How do I access the elements of an array inside this object. For example, if I want the strings inside the array against Ellen Doe, how can I store it inside a variable? I am calling this from an external JSON file using D3.

```
{
  "Marley, Bob": [
    "string 1", 
    "string 2"
  ], 
  "Doe, Ellen": [
    "String 3", 
    "String 2", 

  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the object property through Bracket notation

```
get = object[property_name];
object[property_name] = set;
```

```js
var obj = {
  "Marley, Bob": [
    "string 1", 
    "string 2"
  ], 
  "Doe, Ellen": [
    "String 3", 
    "String 2", 

  ]
}
    console.log(obj["Doe, Ellen"]);
```